# paypal express checkout - 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm using this instruction https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/ to set up paypal. The only different is that I need to send data to CREATE_PAYMENT_URL endpoint, so I transfer it as second parameter

```
paypal.request.post(
                CREATE_PAYMENT_URL,
                JSON.stringify([{"name": "test", "price": 10}]),
                { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }

            )
```

after that I'm getting 400 error

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"statuscode":400,"message":"Invalid json message received"}}
```

Backend doesn't matter, cause it's never reached. Also I'm almost sure it worked fine few days ago 
Any ideas?

Fiddler screen [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the second param to null, and send an options object as the third param with an object named `json` in the third with a plain JS object inside.

```
paypal.request.post(PAYMENT_URL, null, {
    json : {
        name:'test',
        price:10
      }
  })
```

It's not in the documentation, I was having similar issues but dug around in the source code to get it to work.

Comment: thanks man, it works, you are a lifesaver. But wtf? it worked fine maybe 2 weeks ago, and in documentation data in the second parameter. And what means second parameter now if you set it to null?

Comment: it must be used by millions, I can't believe that paypal broke everything, the example from integration doc doesn't work. Maybe it's only for sandbox or something like that?

Comment: Yeah in the documentation they mention putting it as the second parameter, but i noticed if you did that it wouldn't let you send as json unless you did the null / third param. Weird that it's mentioned nowhere! They must have changed their http library they're using to make this work.

Comment: thanks man, I have posted request to paypal, they told me I'm the first who complained about this problem, they are investigating. I will publish an answer here as soon as I get it

Comment: now I have another problem, it doesn't show popup. The error: Refused to display 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ru/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_flow&SESSION=0FFABcyCxAdF-olSaFuLc8gxnJH_bq_uG8fr4nqDFbZgd7Ilh4FcZpfOUm4&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b0819862118003bc2f4b4f47f01ef0a11094f0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. It was worked few days ago. Any ideas?